# Laravel 5.3: Pulo de auto_increment (id) (Gaps)

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Fiz um CRUD básico usando o Eloquent.

Meu problema está na hora de criar (Create). Uso o código abaixo:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $subscription = new Subscription;
    // Basic Data
    $subscription->custom_id = '10001';
    $subscription->service_id = 1;
    $subscription->imported = 1;
    $subscription->review = 0;
    $subscription->inserted_by = \Auth::user()->id;
    $subscription->save();
}
```

Bem simples. Eu consigo inserir dados normalmente. Porém, quando acontece algúm erro (por exemplo o erro *Duplicate entry*) e eu vou inserir o **próximo** registro, ele pula um numero (id) no banco de dados. Vide imagens abaixo

**1) Insiro um registro**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2) Reproduzo um erro**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**3) Insiro o próximo registro normalmente (10002)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que o próximo registro está com `id` 3, e eu acredito que deveria ser 2, pois ele não inseriu o 2º registro pois eu forcei um erro.

**Porque isto acontece?**

**É possível evitar?**

**Isto acontece com todos os sistemas ou só com o Eloquent?**

Comment: Isso absolutamente comum. Parece que o MYSQL cria uma trava no processo de inserção, caso haja erro, a inserção é abortada, mas o `id` inserido continua incrementando. Até porque se tivesse dois processos de inserção ao mesmo tempo, como o Mysql saberia "qual número reservar"?

Comment: O erro está no campo `custom_id`? pelo erro!!! esse campo não pode se repetir?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic meu problema não é o campo repetido e sim os espaços que os erros causam em campos auto_increment no sql :) O erro foi provocado intencionalmente para demonstrar o problema

Comment: Mas, o erro causado pela execção da sua pergunta é pelo campo `custom_id` e por isso acaba acontecendo o pulo da `id` esse campo `custom_id` ele também é uma chave unica?

Comment: Ah sim! É unique também, perdão não entender antes

Comment: Então @wdarking antes de inserir verifique se já existe um `custom_id` .

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, exatamente. Validar antes de executar a query deve ser a maneira mais simples de evitar as lacunas.

Comment: No Laravel com Eloquent se pode fazer isso no `Observer` fica simples a manipulação. @wdarking [observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#observers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já foi explicado muito bem em uma resposta que esse é um comportamento esperado.

Respondendo às outras duas perguntas:

> Isto acontece com todos os sistemas ou só com o Eloquent?

Como foi dito, isso é forma com que o Mysql trabalha. Independente de você fazer controle de transação ou não, isso vai continuar acontecendo. Creio que o Mysql faça isso para evitar problemas internos em relação a definição de uma chave a ser inserida caso haja inserções ocorrendo de vários lugares ao mesmo tempo.

> É possível evitar?

Vou responder com outra pergunta: *Pra quê evitar?*. Se o Mysql já está fazendo assim automaticamente, deixe as coisas por conta dele. Como já foi dito, talvez por questões mais burocráticas (como reserva interna de números da incrementação) o Mysql decidiu que seria melhor assim.

Além do mais, você não precisa ser tão perfeccionista ao ponto de querer que os IDs sejam inseridos certinhos, bonitinhos, tudo na ordem correta.

Na minha opinião, o que importa é que você sempre terá o Mysql gerando uma chave única pra você.

Se for o caso de necessitar da sequência "certinha", faça de outra forma, pois o mecanismo do `AUTO_INCREMENT` é esse mesmo e não há muito o que fazer.

<sub>Talvez enumerar a partir de um loop possa ser a solução, se o problema for só visual.</sub>

## Bônus - E quando eu deleto todos os registros, mas o AUTO_INCREMENT continua?

Se for o caso de você estar querendo "resetar" o AUTO_INCREMENT de sua tabela de pois de ter "zerado" todos os registros que tinha nela, você pode rodar esse comando:

```
ALTER TABLE minha_tabela AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Isso faz com que o contador do AUTO_INCREMENT daquela tabela se inicie do `1`, já que, ao deletar todos os registros, a contagem do AUTO_INCREMENT continua na sequência do último elemento inserido.

Answer (score 1):

Como citou o [Wallace Maxters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4995/wallace-maxters), dei mais uma pesquisada sobre o assunto e o [David Spillett](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60302) deu uma boa explicação:

**Porque isto acontece?**

> Isso não é incomum e há um par de causas. Às vezes é devido a otimizações que o runner de consulta faz para reduzir problemas de contenção com o recurso de contador, melhorando a eficiência quando há atualizações simultâneas para a tabela afetada. Às vezes, é devido a transações que foram explicitamente revertidas (ou implicitamente revertidas devido a encontrar um erro).
>
> As únicas garantias de uma coluna auto_increment (ou IDENTITY em MSSQL
>   e os outros nomes que o conceito passa) é que cada valor será único e
>   nunca menor do que um anterior: assim você pode confiar nos valores
>   para ordenar, mas não pode Confiar neles para não ter lacunas. ***David Spillett***

**É possível evitar?**

> Se você precisar dos valores da coluna para não ter falhas, você
>   precisará gerenciar os valores sozinho, seja em outra camada de lógica
>   de negócios ou no DB por meio de um gatilho (cuidado com potenciais
>   problemas de desempenho com gatilhos).  ***David Spillett***

**Acontece com outros sistemas?**

Pelo que se entende isto é algo que acontece no Mysql. Pode ou não depender de outros sistemas, dependendo se eles permitem o gerenciamento de atributos auto_increment.

Referências também no [Doc do Mysql: AI Handling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html)

Comment: Vou aguardar pra ver se alguém vem com uma resposta mais explicativa